# PHP looping 4 times when it should be saying the number 4

Tags: php, while-loop

Got this code which is troubling me and am eager to accept any help!

```
$x=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($me == $x) 
  {
    echo "You are $me";
    break;
  } 
  else 
  {
    $x++;
  }
}
```

When I include the break; it returns :

> You have selected the 1

However, when I remove the break; it returns

> You have selected the 1 You have selected the 1 You have selected the 1 You have selected the 1

There are currently 6 records in the database and if the code were to work it would display "You are 4th"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your `$x++;` only executes on `else`. In order to have it increment on *every* iteration you need to remove the `else`:

```
$x=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($me == $x) 
  {
    echo "You are $me";
    break;
  }

  $x++;
}
```

Just a side note: `$row` doesn't seem to be related to `$me` and `$x` here. I'll assume your loop contains some other code that you've omitted, but this alone will probably answer your question.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the `$x++;` statement altogether, and post-increment it within the condition (`if ($me == $x++)`). This compares `$me == $x` before incrementing `$x` and is just a more advanced way of doing it.

Comment: I would normally agree with you. However considering the relative simplcity of this problem, i would suggest that the questioner stuck with simple constructs for the time being, when these have been mastered more advance techniques can be used.

Comment: @Andy Paton: I knew someone was going to say that so I left it in a comment instead :)

Comment: -) I added rep anyway - because it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are icrementing $x in the else, this is never getting executed.

You need to do the increment in the same part as the echo.

So either:

```
$x=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($me == $x) 
  {
    echo "You are $me";
    $x++;

  } 
  else 
  {
    $x++;
  }
}
```

Or if you never need to increment $x without echoing:

```
$x=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($me == $x) 
  {
    echo "You are $me";
    x++;
  } 
}
```